# javascript suspends until webview closes?

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, settimeout, suspend

I am writing some web app that runs inside android WebView. The WebView is inside some simple Activity class that I open from the app's main menu. The html file and js files are local files. I'm testing on Asus Transformer TF300, OS 4.1.1.

The WebView loads the html file and a second later calls loadUrl('javascript:start()'); which performs:

```
console.log("hello");
setTimeout("console.log('world');", 1000);
```

When I run it, only "hello" shows up in logcat.
When I close the activity (it has a close button), I suddenly can see "world" in logcat.
It is as if the js suspended itself until I caused the WebView to close...

Any idea why this happens and how to get the code to run?

Note I tried all kinds of stuff like changing the js code to:

```
var func = function() { console.log("world"); };
setTimeout(myfunc, 1000);
```

or:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log("world"); }, 1000);
```

But it didn't help..

thanks.